# Splunk query to return list when a process' first step is logged but its last step is not

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

Splunk count and grouping question...

I have records for various points in a repeated process. At each point four fields are logged: _time, uniqueId, sessionId, and message.

The uniqueId and sessionId are different from each other, but are consistent each time through the process.

The message has several possible values. But I only care about when it is "firstMessage" or "lastMessage".

The logs may look something like this:

| _time | uniqueId | message | sessionId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 12-AB | firstMessage | aaa-3 |
| b | 12-AB | otherMessage | aaa-3 |
| c | 12-AB | lastMessage | aaa-3 |
| d | 28-EA | firstMessage | bbb-5 |
| e | 28-EA | otherMessage | bbb-5 |
| f | 33-A7 | firstMessage | jjj-9 |
| g | 33-A7 | otherMessage | jjj-9 |
| h | 71-3C | firstMessage | uuu-3 |
| i | 71-3C | otherMessage | uuu-3 |
| j | 71-3C | lastMessage | uuu-3 |

I want a table showing all fields when the firstMessage for a uniqueId is recorded, but the lastMessage for that uniqueId is not. That is, the process starts but does not end successfully.

The output I would like, given the above, would be:

| _time | uniqueId | message | sessionId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| d | 28-EA | firstMessage | bbb-5 |
| f | 33-A7 | firstMessage | jjj-9 |

I tried:

```
...start of search... message="firstMessage" OR msg="lastMessage"
| stats count values(message) by uniqueId
| where count < 2
| fields _time uniqueId message sessionId
```

But the time and sessionId columns are blank.

Any and all help is appreciated.

*Yes, _time is supposed to be your basic Splunk Date/Time. I just wasn't typing those out.*

Comment: The time you want is the min(time) for that unique id.  You also need an aggregation for the session-id - how does it change compared to the unique id?  The same unique id can't always have the same session id because if it did why would you have both?  Is it because the same session id can be used for more than one unique id?  If so you can just choose the first session id for that unique id as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to make your stats command create all the fields you want to have. The time you want is the `min(time)` for that uniqueId. You also need an aggregation for the sessionId - if the sessionId is the same for all the events that have a single uniqueId then you can use `min(sessionId)` for that as well:

```
...start of search... message=firstMessage OR message=lastMessage
| stats count values(message) as message, min(_time) as _time, min(sessionId) as sessionId by uniqueId
| where count < 2
| table _time uniqueId message sessionId
```

Here is a runable example - first it makes the raw data then it does the query:

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="
uniqueId message      sessionId
12-AB    firstMessage aaa-3
12-AB    otherMessage aaa-3
12-AB    lastMessage  aaa-3
28-EA    firstMessage bbb-5
28-EA    otherMessage bbb-5
33-A7    firstMessage jjj-9
33-A7    otherMessage jjj-9
71-3C    firstMessage uuu-3
71-3C    otherMessage uuu-3
71-3C    lastMessage  uuu-3
"
| multikv forceheader=1 fields uniqueId message sessionId
| streamstats count
| eval _time=_time-count

| search message=firstMessage OR message=lastMessage
| stats count values(message) as message, min(_time) as _time, min(sessionId) as sessionId by uniqueId
| where count < 2
| table _time uniqueId message sessionId
```

It produces all the fields:

| _time | uniqueId | message | sessionId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-05-26 09:57:07 | 28-EA | firstMessage | bbb-5 |
| 2021-05-26 09:57:05 | 33-A7 | firstMessage | jjj-9 |